# Observable Object to CoreData - Value of type 'NSSet?' has no subscripts

Tags: core-data, swiftui, indices

This was my ModelsConfig

```
    class ModelsConfig: ObservableObject {
    @Published var lists: [ListModel] = []
    @Published var reminders: [Reminder] = []
}
```

and those were my models

```
struct ListModel: Hashable {
    var color: String
    var text: String
    var reminders: [Reminder]
}
struct Reminder: Hashable {
    var title: String
    var notes: String
    var date: Date
    var index: Int
    var list: ListModel
}
```

Before I was able to reach indices in this View as this with the help of ModelsConfig

```
struct ListDetailView: View {
    @Binding var selectedIndex: Int
    @State var isSelected: Bool = false
    @EnvironmentObject var config : ModelsConfig

ForEach(config.lists[selectedIndex].reminders.indices, id: \.self) { reminderIndex in
                            HStack {
                                Button(action: {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1){
                                        deleteReminder(at: reminderIndex)
                                    }
                                    
                                }, label: {
//                                    ReminderCell(reminder: list.reminders[reminderIndex])
                                    ReminderCell(reminder: config.lists[selectedIndex].reminders[reminderIndex])
                                })
                            }
                            .padding(.bottom)
                        }
```

Now, I am trying to reach the same indices with the help of core data as this

```
 @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
    var list: FetchedResults<CDListModel>
ForEach(list[selectedIndex].reminders.indices , id: \.self) { reminderIndex in
                HStack {
                            Button(action: {
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1){
                                    deleteReminder(at: reminderIndex)
                                }
                                
                            }, label: {
                                ReminderCell(reminder: list[selectedIndex].reminders[reminderIndex])
                            })
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom)        
                    }
```

But it does not allow me to do so. How can I reach to indices inside the coredata?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Core Data relationships are `(NS)Set`s. For performance reasons they are unordered.

The easiest solution is to convert the set to an array

```
ForEach((list[selectedIndex].reminders.allObjects as! [CDReminder]).indices , id: \.self) { reminderIndex in
```

Consider to declare the relationship as native `Set<CDReminder>`. Swift `Set`s are a sequence and got indices.